# method not allowed using guzzle

Tags: php, laravel-5, guzzle6

i want delete data by id using guzzle for http request but method not allowed

view file

```
<div class="panel-heading clickable">
 <h3 class="panel-title">
   <a href="/delete/{{$value['id']}}" style="float: right;" data-method="delete">Delete</a>
      {{ $value['nama'] }}
 </h3>
</div>
```

Route file

```
Route::post('/delete/{id}', 'adminController@deleteBidang');
```

Controller File

```
 public function deleteBidang(Request $request){

            $client = new Client([
                'base_uri' => 'http://localhost:8000/api',
                'http_errors' => false,
                'debug' => true
            ]);

            $result = $client->delete('http://localhost:8000/api/admin/kategori/bidang/{id}');

            return redirect('admin/cattegory');


}
```

what the solution ?

Comment: You haven't posted even the original error. Please, respect others users next time and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

You wrongly taking deleting id, use like this.

```
$result = $client->delete("http://localhost:8000/api/admin/kategori/bidang/{$request->id}");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use the laravel url routing in your blade template

```
<a href="{{ url('/delete/'.$value['id']) }}" style="float: right;" data-method="delete">Delete</a>
```

and your controller should look like this. you did not recive the $id in your function. Also the url did not seem right. to my knowlage this should work

```
public function deleteBidang(Request $request, $id){

            $client = new Client([
                'base_uri' => 'http://localhost:8000/api',
                'http_errors' => false,
                'debug' => true
            ]);

            $result = $client->delete('http://localhost:8000/api/admin/kategori/bidang/'.$id);

            return redirect('admin/cattegory');


}
```